# how to 'reset' the units so measures match reality?

Tags: units

I am very new to blender and I took a 2d floorpan and converted it to a 3d model using archimesh.

I have now completed it (amazing, in itself!) but realised my measures are wrong (ie. if a room is 3.69m long in reality, when I measure it with the measure tool, it measures 2.85m in my 3d).

I guess I should have 'stretched' the floorpan at the beginning to make it match the blender units.

Is there a way to 'reset' the units, for example by telling blender that that wall is 3.69m and therefore all the other measure have to be proportionally adjusted?

Comment: Just scale everything together at once until the measurements match then `ctrl+a` > Apply scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale objects in Blender by selecting them and hitting s. If you had some objects that are not scaled correctly and knew that they were 2.85m in some dimension in your scene but need to be 3.69m, then 3.69/2.85=1.294736... so thats the scale value you need to make the objects bigger. You can hit s and type the number while in scaling operation, you can also paste it with ctrl+v.

If you have some 3d model of a house or part of it with correct wall thickness, but wrong room dimensions, then if you scale it, wall thickness is going to be wrong, so you would obviously need to move/remodel walls with correct room dimensions.

Comment: yes I was hoping to avoid having to resize everything manually. If I scale up the entire model, everything will grow (walls, doors, etc...). maybe what I'll do when I place furniture is to decrease their size by the same proportion (1.294736..) so at least it 'fits' in the room.

Comment: That's one really bad idea. If you want to make interior visualisation, or plan your interior design in 3d that's just not how things are done. You must have everything in real size. You cannot plan things with wrong dimensions and even if it's only for practice visualising interior design, it simply looks wrong with wrong sizes. Everything must be correct size in this area. Other way you are simply wasting your time. Don't waste your time, just redo it right...